# Restful API create multiple dependent resources

Tags: backend, rest

I'm questioning myself about how to create an entity that depends on others entity that should have been created previously. Let's have an simple example:

Let's define 3 simple resources:

```
class User {
   // some props
}

class Company {
   users: MongoId[]; // Referencing an array of User object
   logo: MongoId; // Referencing a File object 
}

class File {
   name: string;
   base64: string;
}
```

Now, if I want to create a new company by using a classic `POST /companies` and I send in the body the ids of the previously created Users + File...

But here, I don't know what to do if the company creation fails for x reason (mostly validation error). I previously created 2 entities that will never be used, what should I do about it ? Is there a way in Restful paradigm to avoid this ?

I thought about sending a file AND an array of user in the body instead of ids, to create everything in same time, but it not really Restful.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be up to whomever created the resources to delete them if they no longer need them, and I think that would be the standard approach in a RESTful API. If it's a major concern, you could add methods that would make it easier to keep track of objects that aren't connected to other objects.

Otherwise, the simplest way would be to include them in the body, as you say.

```js
{
    users: [{username: "gooby"}],
    logo: {name: "hello.jpg", base64: "something in base64"}
}
```

You could then return the created company object, with populated IDs if you still want to keep them around as independent resources:

```js
{
    companyId: 15,
    users: [{username: "gooby", id: 74}],
    logo: {name: "hello.jpg", base64: "something in base64", id: 85}
}
```

After which the user could be fetched using e.g. `GET /users/74`.

This means they are still separate resources that can be managed independently. Alternatively you could use client-generated UUIDs in the dependent objects.

You could create some kind of transaction resource which would contain all of your resources in an array and delete them if one of them fails to be created, but it would result in a pretty abstract and unintuitive API.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the second option does not break any Restful "rule" ? I was not sure about that